# Change chapter heading and insert line at top of pages.

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

I'm using this preamble:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphics}                 
\usepackage{color}              
\usepackage{hyperref}             
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}             
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

My problem is that I do not have enough time to completely redo the layout of the hole report, but I would like to fix to things.

1. How do I remove "Chapter" heading and replace it with \chapter{**THIS**}. Like:

   ```
   1 Introduction

   text text text text text text text text text
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   Chapter 1

   Introduction

   text text text text text text text text text
   ```

   Also, I need the "new" heading to be placed at the "Chapter" position.
2. How do i make a line at the top of the pages telling which "chapter" you're in. (not in the appendices though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both requirements can be achieved with the help of the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package (make the necessary adjustments to suit your needs):

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead{\thechapter\  \chaptertitle}{}{}
  \sethead{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

You can use `\pagestyle{plain}` in the body of your document, just before the appendices, to restore the plain page style.

EDIT: the `pdftex` option shouldn't be gived (modern LaTeX systems automatically detect the driver used). Also, the `10pt` option is used by default, so you could safely write

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside]{report}
```

Comment: actually the `pdftex` option does not issue any message, because it's used by **graphicx** and **hyperref**; it shouldn't be given anyway.

Comment: @egreg: you're right. I forgot that the OP was using `graphicx` and `hyperref`.