# Chapter number and chapter title in one line

Tags: sectioning, chapters

This is what I want:

> Chapter 1 : Introduction

but I always get:

> Chapter 1
>
> Introduction

How do I do this?

Comment: Very similar: [How to set the chapter style in report class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/how-to-set-the-chapter-style-in-report-class), [Chapter formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/chapter-formatting) and [Change chapter heading and insert line at top of pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19900/change-chapter-heading-and-insert-line-at-top-of-pages).

Comment: If you are missing chapter numbers: in the \frontmatter chapter numbers are automatically suppressed (which is usually a good idea).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a `KOMA`-class you will not need the package `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=false]{scrreprt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with other classes, it is still possible to redefine the chapter look without using `titlesec`.

Comment: @pluton: Of course but the standard classes don't allow it in such an easy way :-).

Comment: I know tex.stackexchange.com is really nice place, Thanks Marco

Answer (score 33):

You don't say which document class you are using, but for the standard classes, you can adjust these parameters easily with the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{} 

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

You can change the font size as needed, and if you need to change the spacing, there is also a command for that.

Comment: If I am using `scrbook`, and I need the prefix to be `CHAPTER \thechapter: Title` on the **same line** without line break, how can I do it without loading `titlesec`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou  see the other answer. `scrbook` is part of the KOMA classes.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for your response, but I had a problem when using this approach as shown in [my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341474/2288).

Comment: How can one reduce the gap between chapter and section?

Comment: @Adam You can use `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{<leftsep>}{<beforesep>}{<aftersep>}`. So e.g. `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}` would reduce the space after the title to zero.  For chapters, this *only* works if you have also used the `\titleformat` command to define the chapter format.