# TeXLive on Debian GNU/Linux

Tags: xetex, chapters, books

I want the chapter number and heading in one line without the word Chapter, like "1. Introduction", center aligned for a book class document. I have seen the solution here: [Chapter number and chapter title in one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/chapter-number-and-chapter-title-in-one-line), that gives the title aligned left. I would like to know what I can add or change to align it to the center.

Comment: I am wondering how the title of your question relates to the actual question, and I'd like to encourage you to make a more appropriate choice in order to draw the attention of the relevant folks to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25031/121799) and `texdoc titlesec` suggests

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{} 

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to fine-tune @marmot's answer to the requirements of @Sasi, [who probably wants "1. Introduction" instead of "Chapter 1:   Introduction"] I think
1.  either the `\chaptername` should be reset to a blank `{}` with
`\renewcommand{\chaptername}{{}}` ...or 
2. avoid it in the `\titleformat` definition as : `\titleformat{\chapter}[block] {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\thechapter.}{1ex}{}`

Comment: @ParthaD. Thanks! (If you want, you could write your own answer, or do you want me to merge this into mine?)

Comment: Thank you so much. marmot's code helped to get what I wanted as I had already reset chapter name to a blank.

Comment: @marmot: Since you have solved essentially every aspect of the problem superbly [only possibly overlooked one minor requirement which I pointed out-- and Sasi could have solved by himself] I probably do not owe any original contribution to this post.  So I think it's better if you can edit the MWE to that effect.