# CHAPTER ONE and not CHAPTER 1 in the body of a thesis

Tags: formatting, chapters, thesis

Thanks to @AlanMunn for the answers given in the question asked in the link.

[Chapter number and chapter title in one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/chapter-number-and-chapter-title-in-one-line)

What I want is:

**CHAPTER ONE:** the chapter name/title

and not

**Chapter 1:** The chapter name/title

I was able to do this

**CHAPTER 1:** the chapter name/title

I need to change "1" to "ONE" without affecting anything on the toc.

I used the following code

```
\usepackage{titletoc,fmtcount,titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}% this reduces the space between the chapter title and section
```

Please how do I go about it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you also want CHAPTER ONE in the table of contents?

Comment: @Benard yes I have done that already.

Answer (score 1):

Since you load `fmtcount`, it is particularly easy for the chapter heading:

```
\usepackage{titletoc,fmtcount,titlesec} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \NUMBERstring{chapter}:}{1em}{}
```

Comment: thanks so much. It worked.