# How to create a Chapter 1: TITLE in table of contents and header in the document?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, koma-script, scrreprt

In my table of contents I would like to insert a "Chapter 1:", "Chapter 2:", etc.  with the chapters after the introduction: 
`\mychapter{2}{Title}` and then goes on. It should be in the same line.

Additionally, would it also be possible to put it in the header above each `\mychapter{2}{TITLE}`, `\mychapter{3}{TITLE}`, `\mychapter{4}{TITLE}` ?

This is my document class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{scrreprt}
```

A reason for using `\mychapter` was that the number which is usually displayed before every chapter gets deleted.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What is this ``\mychapter`` command?

Comment: Usually there is a 1 Introduction when you use \chapter, but by using \mychapter, the number is deleted in front of it.

Comment: Please show the definition of `\mychapter`.

Comment: Usually when \chapter is used there is a number before the title (1 Introduction). By using \mychapter instead of  \chapter the number disappears.

Comment: I just copy pasted it from somewhere on the internet. I myself don't understand it:\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}

Comment: this is everything I got :/

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/chapter-number-and-chapter-title-in-one-line would it be possible to transfer this to \mychapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of the chapter should not be displayed in the headings use

`\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}`

But if you want a prefix line for the chapter headings use class option `chapterprefix` and

```latex
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}
```

to add the colon after the number.

To change the format of the entry in the page header use

`\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp\ \thechapter\autodot:\enskip}`

and for the TOC entry

```latex
\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}#1\autodot}{#2}}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  chapterprefix,% use a prefix line for chapters
  numbers=noenddot% no dot at the end of numbers
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}

\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}#1\autodot}{#2}}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\appendix
\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! How can I also display Chapter 1 above the title of the page itself?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I think I did not really understand it. Now I removed all my \mychapters and replaced them with \chapter ... however my appendix should not be displayed as Chapter No. : Appendix in the toc. How can I remove the chapter here?

Comment: also how can I center "chapter: title"? As it is displayed on the left side of the page?

Comment: Could you please give an example on how to not display the "chapter number" in the toc but the title. E.g. I would like my Appendix not to have a chapter + number (neither displayed on the page). but set the counter from a specific \chapter.

Comment: There was not an appendix in your question, but I have updated my answer again. To center the chapter heading you can use `\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}`. Please ask a new question (including a  minimal working example) if there are other issues.

Comment: thanks! Sorry for asking so much!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530323/how-to-remove-chapter-number-in-the-toc-and-on-the-page-itself-from-particu would you please be so kind and help me out?