# How to remove "Chapter: [Number]" in the toc and on the page itself from particular chapters?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, koma-script, scrreprt

I was given the following code for creating a "chapter" on top of the page, followed by the "title" of the page, which is displayed below "chapter".

This is the document class I use:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
```

I have the following problem: 
I would like only particular \chapters to display "chapter: [number]" in the toc before a "title". The title should still be displayed just without "chapter: [number]". Right now all my \chapters display a chapter: [number] in front of the title in the toc and on the page.

Also, how to I remove the colons that appear after "Chapter[:]" on the page (but leave them in the table of contents)?

Additionally, by applying the \documentclass that was given to me something changed. I don't know whether the font got smaller but my pages shrank from about 60 to 54. Any idea?

```
\pagestyle{headings} %chapter in toc and on page (numbering)

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp\ \thechapter\autodot:\enskip}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat=\tocentrywithprefix{\chapapp},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}
\newcommand\tocentrywithprefix[2]{\mbox{#1~#2:}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}
```

Comment: For the number of pages that shrank, in your [last post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530315/how-to-create-a-chapter-1-title-in-table-of-contents-and-header-in-the-document) you used the option ``12pt`` with the class ``scrreprt``, but here you removed it. Maybe it's only that the font size shrank from 12pt to 11pt. You could try to put the option ``12pt`` back.

Comment: \documentclass[chapterprefix][12pt]{scrreprt} Latex displays an error if I do it like that.

Comment: Try ``\documentclass[12pt,chapterprefix]{scrreprt}``.

Comment: thanks it worked! Unfortunately, I still haven't worked out my main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `:` from the chapter heading, remove the redefinition of `\chapterformat`. It was only redefined to add the colon.

Unfortunaly I do not understand what you really want to do.

If the prefix should be removed only in appendix, you can use

```latex
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  chapterprefix,
  %appendixprefix=false,% no prefixline for appendix chapters
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}

\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}#1\autodot}{#2}}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}

\let\originalappendix\appendix
\renewcommand*{\appendix}{%
  \originalappendix
  %\renewcommand*\chapterformat{}% remove the chapter number  from chapter heading
  %\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}% remove the chapter number from header entry
  \renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{% remove the chapter number from ToC entry
    \originaladdchaptertocentry{}{##2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\appendix
\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

If you only want to use unnumbered chapters with ToC and header entry, replace `\chapter` by `\addchap`:

```latex
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  chapterprefix,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}

\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}#1\autodot}{#2}}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}% unnumbered chapter
\lipsum
\chapter{Foo}% numbered chapter
\lipsum
\appendix
\addchap{Bar}% unnumbered chapter
\lipsum
\chapter{Numbered}% numbered chapter
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, again! This was just what I needed