# How to change the chapter format?

Tags: chapters, koma-script

I would like the name Chapter [No.] on top, below the actual `\chapter`.

[image] <- I want it like this.

[image] <- but it looks currently like this.

> I would like the format of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB0Uo.png) but not its size of the fonts; the font like in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmAh9.png).

```
\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily \LARGE}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalfont \itshape }

%code below here does not seem to work
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering} %chapter in toc and on page (numbering)
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}
\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}#1\autodot}{#2}}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}

\let\originalappendix\appendix
\renewcommand*{\appendix}{%
  \originalappendix
  %\renewcommand*\chapterformat{}% remove the chapter number  from chapter heading
  %\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}% remove the chapter number from header entry
  \renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{% remove the chapter number from ToC entry
    \originaladdchaptertocentry{}{##2}%
  }%
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It seems you've slightly misunderstood the function of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`. It changes **all** section headings to the `rmdefault` font, you don't need to add `\rmfamily` to `addtokomafont` or `setkomafont` commands for headings.

Comment: @TivV okay I think I understand now; I am sorry I am not good with LateX

Comment: See my answer to your previous question: [How to create a Chapter 1: TITLE in table of contents and header in the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530319/43317)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KOMA-Script option for this is called `chapterprefix` (it can be found in the KOMA Script Manual in section "3.16. Document Structure").

```
\documentclass[
    egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
    headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
    chapterprefix=true
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\LARGE}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalfont \itshape}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]