# Format chapter title and use package `babel`

Tags: babel, titlesec, languages

I want to make the chapter number and title to be in the same line as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25030/100231) question. However, when I want to apply the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25031/100231), it does not work with the `package` `babel` with the option 'magyar'.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

% \usepackage[magyar]{babel}  % Does not work
\usepackage[english]{babel}   % Works

  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output with 'magyar' and with 'english']

Does anybody have an idea how to use `\titleformat` and `babel` together?

**EDIT**

According to @esdd answer the key is to use

```
\def\magyarOptions{chapterhead=unchanged}
```

before

```
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
```

In this case, I had to reformat `chapter` title manually (to be 'magyar'):

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\arabic{chapter}. Fejezet:}{1ex}{}
```

Comment: Hungarian seems to be special: https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/What's-new-in-babel-3.48

Comment: Try `\def\magyarOptions{chapterhead=unchanged}` before `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}`.

Comment: Thank you @esdd! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `\def\magyarOptions{chapterhead=unchanged}` before loading package `babel` with option `magyar`.

```latex
\def\magyarOptions{chapterhead=unchanged}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\magyarOptions{chapterhead=unchanged}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}

\renewcommand*{\chaptertitlename}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\chaptername}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\appendix}
  {\gdef\chaptertitlename{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\appendixname}}
  {}{\undefined}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]