# How to make one line chapter headings?

Tags: sectioning

At the moment my headings are as follows:

**Chapter 1**

**Title of chapter**

Is there anyway to reformat the headings so that they are all on one line? i.e.

**Chapter 1: Title of chapter**

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This may depend on the document class you're using. Could you post  a small, yet complete code illustrating your problem?

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean. Currently, I am using the report class but having switched it to the article class it seems to do what I want it to. However, it means I need to completely reformat my document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chapter number and chapter title in one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25030/163512)

Comment: The article class doesn't have chapters. . For chapters, it is either the report or the book class. It is simple to obtain the formatting you want with the advanced interface – something like `\titleformat{\chapter}{\LARGE\bfseries}[\chaptername~\thechapter}{1em}{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to customize the chapter titles. There are several ways to do it.

But with foresight you will also want to harmonize section titles, subsection, etc.

There are several parameters to take into account: the font and style of the chapter/section  name and the chapter/section title, their relative positions, etc. and also the vertical spaces before and after. The same with subsection, part, ...

With the `titlesec` package you get a nice interface to play with these parameters, using the familiar LaTeX commands, until you get the result you like best.

There are two commands `\titleformat` and `\titlepacing` to use for quick setup (manual section #2 only).

[image: z]

This is the code used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{titlesec} % added <<<<<<

%%%%%%%%%% chapters
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command to format
[block] % shape: hang, display, block, frame etc
{\sffamily\bfseries\Large}  % format of label + chapter title
{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:} % label "Chapter 1:"
{1.5ex} % separation label - chapter title
{} % code before

\titlespacing{\chapter}
{0pt} %left of the label + title
{*0} % vertical space before the title
{*6.5} % idem after title (in ex units + glue)


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  sections
\titleformat{\section}
[block] % shape 
{\sffamily\bfseries\itshape}% format (keep the chapter font family!)
{\thesection.} % label "1.1."
{0.8ex}% separation label -  section title 
{}

\titlespacing{\section}
{0pt} %left of label + section title
{*4} % before the label + section title
{*1.5} % after 

\begin{document}

\chapter{The First}
1. \kant[1]

\section{A section}
2. \kant[2] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `book` class, for example, it seems that `\chapter` calls `\@chapter` which in turns calls `\@makechapterhead`, with the following definition:

```
\@makechapterhead:
macro:#1->\vspace *{50\p@ }{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter \huge \bfseries \@chapapp \space \thechapter \par \nobreak \vskip 20\p@ \fi \fi \interlinepenalty \@M \Huge \bfseries #1\par \nobreak \vskip 40\p@ }
```

Redefining this to remove the paragraph break etc. between `\thechapter` and the chapter title, `#1`, appears to work:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
\vspace *{50\p@ }{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont %
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter \huge \bfseries %
\@chapapp \space \thechapter: \bfseries #1\par \nobreak \vskip 40\p@ }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can replace `\huge` in the (re)definition above with e.g. `\Huge` etc., as desired.