# How can I put chapter number and chapter title in one line in memoir?

Tags: memoir, titlesec

I want to put chapter number and chapter title in one line and i found this code that works well:
([Chapter number and chapter title in one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/chapter-number-and-chapter-title-in-one-line))

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{} 

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

However it uses the titlesec package that is incompatible with memoir class that use in my book. It is possible to achieve the same result in another not-titlesec depended way?

Comment: Could you show a MWE for the memoir class which is incompatible.

Comment: Isn't this more or less a variation over the section chapter style in memoir. It is not hard to do. Not at pc, so will have a look tomorrow. Basically the macros that print the chapter+number line has to be redefined to do nothing. The midskip macro (don't remember the name) also gave to do nothing. Then redefine printchaptertitle to print chapter+number+title.

Answer (score 2):

`memoir` provides the commands to create custom chapter styles without additional packages.[image: a]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{sectionx}{% define the new style
\chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\chaptitlefont \chaptername}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\thechapter:}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\hspace{1em}}
}   
\chapterstyle{sectionx}% use the style

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Highly recommended reading for memoir users:  [Chapter styles in memoir class](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoirchapterstyles?lang=en).